# Sublime tset: standard error: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3

I just installed Sublime 3 on my Mac running OSX and I'm just trying to ensure that my environment is set up correctly for running Python scripts.

Upon running the below code:

```
def main():
    print('hello world')
main()
```

I get the following output:

```
tset: standard error: Inappropriate ioctl for device

hello world
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Any idea why I am getting the tset:standard error?

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the operating system. If it's a `*nix` system you need to mark the file as an executable.

`chmod +x filename.py`

I might be wrong. But this is worth giving a try.

Comment: I am on Mac OSX El Cap. So i need to change the chmod of the file to be executable first?

Comment: Setting the execute bit is only required for when you want to execute a script or binary directly from the shell.  Other options like via `python script.py` or `ldd /path/to/binary` don't require an execute bit.